# How to convert SUM() result to JSON?

Tags: php

I want to convert SUM() to json. My App send user data and wants to receive SUM of some values, but its not working.

If you know what i did wrong, help me

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    include 'DatabaseConfig.php';
    $UniqueID= $_POST['UniqueID'];
    $month = date("Y-m");
    $conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(points) AS totalsum FROM history WHERE unique_id = '$UniqueID' AND month = '$month'" ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo "Nic Nie Znaleziono.";
    } else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $sum = $row['totalsum'];
        $json = json_encode($sum);
    }
    echo $json;
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Error:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
              at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
              at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
              at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
              at com.pieterapps.notesministranta.Home$PointsInMonthGetHttpResponse.doInBackground(Home.java:349)
              at com.pieterapps.notesministranta.Home$PointsInMonthGetHttpResponse.doInBackground(Home.java:324)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Not working __how__? Please read [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: Please add error render

Comment: App doesnt receive data; SUM() works but other things not

Comment: What does your SQL query returns ?

Comment: Have you tried passing the data as `$json = json_encode(["sum" => $sum]);` as opposed to just the value `$sum`?

Comment: @NigelRen this is what i receive: {"sum":null}

Comment: I'd check your getting `$UniqueID` and `$month` values your expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the way you are using the json_encode.

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an array. Reference [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

By doing $row['totalsum'] you are setting $sum to a single variable and not array.  json_encode requires an array.

You can simply change the code to

> $json = json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

It might be best to perform some kind of test to ensure a sum is returned from the query.

Comment: but with this code json !=null :                                                                          foreach($conn->query("SELECT SUM(points) FROM history WHERE unique_id = '$UniqueID' AND month = '$month'") as $row) {
$sum = $row['SUM(points)'];
$json = json_encode(["totalsum" => $sum]); 
}
 echo $json;

Comment: LOG: ##### User id : ='5bccd446728e24.01249167'#####
##### Month : ='2018-10'#####
##### SUM : ='{"totalsum":"44"}'#####

Comment: `json_encode()` does NOT require an array. See PHP reference.